# An application of Frobenius theorem.

Tags: differential-topology, vector-fields

Using the Frobenius theorem, how can one show that does not exist a non-constant smooth function defined in a open and connected subset of $\mathbb R^4$ satisfying:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + x \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \frac{x^2}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = 0, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + x \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = 0 \quad (I). $$

Some effort:

Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function defined in a connected and open subset of $\mathbb R^4$ satisfying $(I)$. Take the vector fields
$$ X =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \quad Y = \frac{\partial }{\partial y} + x \frac{\partial }{\partial z} + \frac{x^2}{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial w}, \quad Z = \frac{\partial }{\partial z} + x \frac{\partial }{\partial w}. $$

Computing their Lie brackets follows that

$$ [X,Y] = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial w} = Z \quad \text{ and } \quad [Y,Z] = 0, $$
however $[Z,X] = - \frac{\partial}{\partial w}$ which is not spanned by $X,Y, Z$, with this I can conclude that  the distribution $\mathcal D$ spanned by $X,Y,Z$ is not involutive and by Frobenius theorem it can't be integrable. I'm stucked in what to do whith that , so I can conclude that $f$ must be constant.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a basic level, $Xf=0$ and $Zf=0$ implies $[X,Z]f=0$, i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=0$. Then from the original equations $(I)$ we deduce that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$, implying $f$ is constant.

More geometrically, you could say that $\mathcal{E}:=\operatorname{span}\lbrace X, Y, Z,[X,Z]\rbrace$ defines an involutive distribution, which is easily shown to have rank 4. Therefore the integral manifold of $\mathcal{E}$ through any point must be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, and $f$ will be constant on this set.

Comment: About the "more geometrically" part. How can you explain the part that you conclude that $f$ is constant saying that the integral manifold being an open subset? I thought you should get something like in the "basic" level part. I just can't see a way to put Frobenius theorem in the solution.

Comment: Suppose $\mathcal{E}$ is any involutive distribution (hence integrable by Frobenius), and $Vf=0$ for $V$ a section of $\mathcal{E}$ (i.e. $V$ is a vector field such that $V_x \in \mathcal{E}_x$ for all $x$ in the region considered). Then $f$ will be constant along the integral manifolds of $\mathcal{E}$ (since each integral manifold is a union of all integral curves of sections of $\mathcal{E}$, and $f$ is constant along each such integral curve). In your case, the involutive distribution has rank 4, so the integral manifolds have dimension 4, and so must be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: So $f$ is constant on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Not sure if this answers your question?

Comment: Since sections of $\mathcal E$ are connected and $Vf = 0$, you can conclude that the $f$ is constant?

Comment: Let's back up. By "section of $\mathcal{E}$" I just mean a vector field that is always contained in $\mathcal{E}$. If you have such a vector field $V$, and $Vf=0$, then $f$ is constant along the integral curve of $V$. Does this much make sense to you?

Comment: Ok, now I think I got it, $f$ must be constant, because if $\gamma$ is the integral curve of $V$, we have $0 = Vf = df_{\gamma}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99415/discussion-between-user17945-and-user-242964).

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use the $1$-form characterization of distributions: if $f$ is not constant then $df$ is a non-zero $1$-form that annihilates $D=\text{span}\ \{X,Y,Z\}$ so $D\subseteq \text{ker}\ df$. But $\text{dim}\ D=3$ and $\text{dim Im}\ df=1$ implies that $\text{dim ker}\ df=3$ so in fact, $D= \text{ker}\ df.$ Thus, $df$ is a defining form for $D$. Clearly $ddf$ annihilates $D$. This implies that $D$ is involutive, and we have a contradiction.